# Get mosaic images metadata using CSW

Tags: geoserver, metadata, mosaic

I am trying to get metadata of each mosaic image element defined with its attributes using `datastore.properties` postgis indexing method. Is it possible to get that info in some way using Geoserver CSW service? I tried GetRecords type of request but it only returns layer metadata.

Request:

**endpoint**

```
/geoserver/csw
```

**reqBody**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetRecords service="CSW" version="2.0.2" maxRecords="50" startPosition="1" resultType="results" outputFormat="application/xml" outputSchema="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 ../../../csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd">
  <Query typeNames="csw:Record">
    <ElementSetName typeNames="csw:Record">full</ElementSetName>
    <Constraint version="1.1.0">
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="%" singleChar="_" escapeChar="\">
          <ogc:PropertyName>dc:title</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>%esat%</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
      </ogc:Filter>
    </Constraint>
  </Query>
</GetRecords>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csw:GetRecordsResponse xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 http://192.168.180.132:9091/geoserver/schemas/csw/2.0.2/record.xsd">
    <csw:SearchStatus timestamp="2022-12-15T16:14:46.543Z"/>
    <csw:SearchResults numberOfRecordsMatched="1" numberOfRecordsReturned="1" nextRecord="0" recordSchema="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" elementSet="full">
        <csw:Record>
            <dc:identifier>testiranje_rastera:esat3</dc:identifier>
            <dc:creator>GeoServer Catalog</dc:creator>
            <dct:references scheme="OGC:WMS">http://192.168.180.132:9091/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&amp;request=GetMap&amp;layers=testiranje_rastera:esat3</dct:references>
            <dc:subject>esat3</dc:subject>
            <dc:subject>WCS</dc:subject>
            <dc:subject>ImageMosaic</dc:subject>
            <dc:description>Generated from ImageMosaic</dc:description>
            <dc:title>esat3</dc:title>
            <dc:type>http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/Dataset</dc:type>
            <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.11:4326">
                <ows:LowerCorner>45.75093578854459 16.035794771100694</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>45.9313002833765 16.152964170260535</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:BoundingBox>
        </csw:Record>
    </csw:SearchResults>
</csw:GetRecordsResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer internal CSW can provide metadata on single layer and on services only, but not on the single images part of a mosaic.

It could be added, with some coding. See here if you are interested in pursuing it:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-fixes,-improvements-and-new-features-in-GeoServer

Comment: is there maybe a way to get metadata of granules which mosaic is consisted of using some of other services...WCS maybe ?

Comment: The WCS-EO extension provides some of that information: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wcs20eo/index.html

Comment: It seems that it isn't working properly without time dimension being set on queried layer, but I am also having problem with that https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448108/enable-time-dimension-in-geoserver-on-imagemosaic-coverage