# Enable time dimension in GeoServer on imageMosaic coverage

Tags: geoserver, time-series

I am trying to enable time dimension on my imageMosaic which consist of TIFF files served from S3. I've been following different GeoServer tutorials for setting up the mosaic:

- https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html
- https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html
- https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/cog/update.html

First I pushed my TIFFs in COG format on S3 bucket and after that
created the directory `esat3` which I browsed as root directory for my image mosaic store.
After store creation index shapefile is generated with all its  accompanying files. I deleted them because I decided to use PostGIS table for indexing of my mosaic.

My `datastore.properties` which is used for generating index props

```
 user=postgres
 port=5432
 passwd=PW
 host=HOST
 database=esat
 driver=org.postgresql.Driver
 schema=public
 SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
 fetch\ size=1000
 max\ connections=20
 min\ connections=5
 validate\ connections=true
 Loose\ bbox=true
 Expose\ primary\ key=false
 Max\ open\ prepared\ statements=50
 preparedStatements=false
 Estimated\ extends=false
 Connection\ timeout=20
```

I also defined and configured `MOSAICNAME.properties` and `indexer.properties` files

`MOSAICNAME(esat3).properties`

```
Cog=true
ExpandToRGB=false
TypeName=esat3
SuggestedFormat=org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat
SuggestedSPI=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.CogImageReaderSpi
Name=esat3
LevelsNum=9
PathType=RELATIVE
Heterogeneous=true
Caching=false
HeterogeneousCRS=false
LocationAttribute=location
Levels=0.25,0.25 1.0,1.0 2.0,2.0 4.0,4.0 8.0,8.0 16.0427807486631,16.0 
32.25806451612903,32.25806451612903 65.21739130434783,64.51612903225806 
130.43478260869566,133.33333333333334
CheckAuxiliaryMetadata=false
MosaicCRS=EPSG\:3765
```

`indexer.properties`

```
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
Name=esat3
```

`timeregex.properties` can also be found on my directory

```
regex=[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2},format=yyyy.MM.dd
```

After `datastore.properties` creation `esat` database is generated automatically. I had to manually create  table `esat3` with all its columns (`the_geom,location,ingestion`) defined inside `indexer.properties -> schema`  and also populate it the same way manually.

Column definitions `esat3`:

```
-- Table: public.esat3

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.esat3;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.esat3
(
    the_geom geometry(Geometry,3765),
    location character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ingestion timestamp without time zone
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.esat3
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Here is example of my location path:
`http://192.168.180.132:9444/esat/2020.04.27.tif`

It all works fine. My images are properly rendering when I fetch them over WMS. The only problem is I can't enable time dimension. It says *Cannot enable, no attribute of type Date found*. I tried with different date time formats on `ingestion` column in PostgreSQL but there isn't any effect. What am I overlooking?  I have already spent few days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing too much work and not letting the mosaic automations set up for itself. Please see this tutorial, just setup the config files (datastore/indexer) and let everything else be created by the mosaic machinery:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/cog/mosaic.html